Independent events - probability
We are given 3 events $A,B,C$ such that :
$P(A\cap B \cap C)=P(A\cap B)P(C)$
$P(A\cap B \cap C^c)=P(A\cap B)P(C^c)$
$P(A\cap B^c \cap C)=P(A\cap B^c)P(C)$
$P(A^c\cap B \cap C)=P(A^c\cap B)P(C)$
The question given is - prove \ disprove - $A$ and $C$ are independent events. which just means to show that $P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C)$ or provide a counter example for which all the conditions mentioned are satsfied but $P(A\cap C)\neq P(A)P(C)$
after a couple of tries trying to prove this and failing, I started to think this might actually be a disproof question, but I'm having a hard time trying to find a counter-example. I tried some "edge" cases like $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive events, or setting some of the events to be $0$, but I just cant seem to find one example that satisfies all of the conditions mentioned in the question.
Any help would be much appreciated!
